# flutter GestureDetector swipe while onlongPress

Tags: flutter, dart

a button should be long pressed to record something. **If during the long press a swipe is detected** the record should be deleted.

I tried to combine onLongPressStart/End with onPanUpdate, but it doesn't work

```
     GestureDetector(
      child: Icon(Icons.mic_none_outlined),
      onLongPressStart: (_) async {
        setState(() {
          startRecording = true;  //start recording
        });
        do {
          await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
        } while (startRecording );
      },
      onLongPressEnd:  (_) async {
        setState(() {
          startRecording = false; //end recording
        });
      },
      onPanUpdate: (details) {              //<----- not working
        // Swiping in left direction    
        if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
          //delete record
        }
      },
    ),
```

Comment: instead of `onPanUpdate` check other `onLongPress*` properties

Comment: thanks, you are right, onLongPressMoveUpdate did the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code works:

```
 GestureDetector(
  child: Icon(Icons.mic_none_outlined),
  onLongPressStart: (_) async {
    setState(() {
      startRecording = true;  //start recording
    });
    do {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    } while (startRecording );
  },
  onLongPressEnd:  (_) async {
    setState(() {
      startRecording = false; //end recording
    });
  },
  onLongPressMoveUpdate:(movement) async {
    if (movement.offsetFromOrigin.dx < -300) {
      print("------------------swipe detection------------------------");
    }
      },
),
```